# Excel vba: copy values in a range to another workbook using R1C1 formula

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy the values in a range of a workbook to another one using the `R1C1` formula instead of `A1` formula (because I'd like to replace the row value by an integer variable in my code later on).

So this code works for me:

```
 Sub test()
   Dim x, y As Workbook

   Set x = ThisWorkbook
   Set y = Workbooks.Open("myfilepath")

   x.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B1").Copy
   y.Sheets(1).Range("A32:B32").PasteSpecial

 End Sub
```

However if I try something like that (which I think is equivalent) it doesn't work (I get a `'1004' error at x.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)).Copy`):

```
Sub test()
  Dim x, y As Workbook

  Set x = ThisWorkbook
  Set y = Workbooks.Open("myfilepath")

  x.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)).Copy
  y.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(32, 1), Cells(32, 2)).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Can someone explain why it doesn't work and how how could use an integer variable to define my row instead of letters?

Comment: fyi, `x` is declared as a `variant`.

Comment: @findwindow: Thanks. I was wondering why typing "x." was not showing the dropdown menu of possiblities while typing "y." was.

Comment: As a side-note to the accepted answer; you can still use R1C1 notation and achieve what you want. VBA accepts the following syntax: `Range("A" & someVariable)`

Comment: @Vegard: Thanks for the comment. You're right. I'll keep that in mind for next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the parent object for the `Cells`, like

```
x.Sheets(1).Range(x.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), x.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2)).Copy
y.Sheets(1).Range(y.Sheets(1).Cells(32, 1), y.Sheets(1).Cells(32, 2)).PasteSpecial
```

For more compact code you may use `With` blocks:

```
With x.Sheets(1)
 .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 2)).Copy
End With
With y.Sheets(1)
 .Range(.Cells(32, 1), .Cells(32, 2)).PasteSpecial
End With
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex!! It works for me.  I spent so much time trying to find an answer and you got it in 5 min.  Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. Good luck with your project. Best regards,